# Output System.Diagnostics.Debug to Console

Tags: .net, .net-core

I want to get output from `System.Diagnostigs.Debug` in NET Core. Any way is appreciated, but the best I would like to see the output from `Debug` in Console. I try to use such code:

```
TextWriterTraceListener myWriter = new 
   TextWriterTraceListener(System.Console.Out);
Debug.Listeners.Add(myWriter);
```

But receive an error:

> 'Debug' does not contain a definition for 'Listeners'

What am I missing? Is it possible to use `System.Diagnostics.Debug` in .NET Core?

I use `netcoreapp1.0` framework.

UPDATE:
For Windows I have found a tool DebugView, which shows the output from `Debug`, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx, but the question is still actual for Linux and `Console` output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In .Net Framework, `Debug.WriteLine` and `Trace.WriteLine` are the same, the only difference is that `Debug.WriteLine` is enabled when the `DEBUG` symbol is set, while `Trace.WriteLine` is enabled when the `TRACE` symbol is set.

In .Net Core, `Trace.WriteLine` still behaves like that, but `Debug.WriteLine` has a completely different implementation and does not use `Listeners`, I'm not sure why (you might consider asking at [the corefx repo](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx)).

[The Unix implementation of `Debug.WriteLine`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d0dc5fc099946adc1035b34a8b1f6042eddb0c75/src/Common/src/System/Diagnostics/Debug.Unix.cs) also has explicit check for the `COMPlus_DebugWriteToStdErr` envirnment variable, and when its set, it will output `Debug.WriteLine` to the standard error output.

This means if you use `COMPlus_DebugWriteToStdErr=1 dotnet run` to run your application, it will work.

If you actually want to use listeners, you will need to use `Trace.WriteLine`.

Comment: Hello. Visual Studio newbie here. "`Debug.WriteLine` is enabled when the `DEBUG` symbol is set"... how do I set the `DEBUG` symbol?

Comment: @ocramot It's set by default in Debug mode. You can change it in project properties.